# Jquery stops before for loop

Tags: jquery

i am trying to adjust a div font-size depending on its height

i get the elements with class "prod-name" with .each

```js
 $prod_names = new Array();
    $i=0;
    $j=0;

    $(".prod-name").each(function(){
       $prod_names[$i] = $(this);
       $i++;
    });

    for($j=0;$j>=$i;$j++){
        console.log("in for");
    if(($prod_names[$j].height() > 20) && ($prod_names[$j].height() <= 40)){
        console.log("ok");
        $prod_names[$j].css("font-size","0.9em");
    }else if($prod_names[$j].height() > 40){
        $prod_names[$j].css("font-size","0.8em");
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mostviewed" class="products">
    <h2 class="cat-title">MOST VIEWED</h2>
    <ul>
        <li class="scol25  mcol25 lcol25" >
            <a href="product.php" class="prod-img"><img src="images/products/.jpg" title=""/></a>
            <p class="prod-name">Intel Core I3</p>
            <div class="prices">
                <p id="original-price" class="scol50 mcol50 lcol50 price">&euro;</p>
                <p id="low-price" class="scol50 mcol50 lcol50 price">&euro;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="fa-buttons">
                <a id="morea" class="scol50 mcol50 lcol50 add1"  title="More information" href="product.php"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a id="fava" href="#" class="scol50 mcol50 lcol50 add1" title="Add to favorites"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i added logs to see if it reaches the code in the loop and it doesnt

note: in reality i use php but for better understanding of my problem i changed it to html

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the logic here... Assuming there are 4 `prod-name` elements, then $i will be 4, while $j is 0, so `$j>=$i` is false hence won't get in the loop..

I bet you shall reconsider the aim of this code and write it in a neater way.

Answer (score 0):

i see so one of the parameters of the for loop is false...

thank you, i know the code is extended and complicated but im a beginner in jquery and as i go on i will make the code better

thank you